# how to edit registry of xp installation disc

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installation, regedit

I want to add some of my application to xp installation and lunch them after xp startup.I can add program using regedit manually to startup after install but,i dont know how to edit registry of xp installation cd.I want to add those application to xp installation disc's registry run(I386/REGEDIT.EXE)before installing xp.how can i do that?please anybody tell me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nlite](http://www.nliteos.com) to customize the XP setup disk. Among many other things it allows you to [add entries to the registry.](http://www.nliteos.com/addons/#registry_addreg).

However this is not a 5 minute task, you have to learn the tool and some concepts first.

Comment: Thank you sir for your replay.If you don't mind can you tell me the steps to edit registry using nlite or can you give me a easy tutorial link of nlite regedit tips?

Comment: There are some tutorials on the site, and also 3rd party blog posts about it. I have not used the tool for at least 5 years, so I don't remember the details.